# Why UITableView can always scroll but UIScrollView can't

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

No matter what content size of `UITableView`, it can always scroll. but now I want `UIScrollView` also like it.....

At first, I use the code like this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 63);
```

It does work, but now I use AutoLayout, it said I must certain a content size.

the app have to adapt to iPhone4~iPhone 6 Plus, so the content size can't be certain, it always small than screen subtract 1, just like this (because the state bar and the navigation bar take over 64 px)

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 63);
```

BTW, if I don't certain a size, and write this code in `- (void)viewDidLoad` ,while Xcode compile it just a warming, don't affect the APP running.

I hope you can give me some better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solve this issue, just add this `scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES`, then I can scroll the ScrollView no matter if the content beyond the frame

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I barely understand what you want.

Now the technical part:

1. It's not a good practice, hell, you should never change the content size of a `UITableView`, `UITableView` always compute his content size based on `heightFirRowAtIndexPath`, `heightForHeader...` and the other `heightFor...` methods, that's why the table will scroll (of course if the methods are implemented right)
2. The `UIScrollview` won't compute the content size by itself because it's not designed that way, so you'll have to specify the content size for it. Usually when a `UIScrollView` doesn't scroll it's because the `contentSize` it's smaller than the scroll's frame size so it doesn't have to scroll.
3. Implementing a `UIScrollView` with auto-layout it's a little tricky and you have to do some tweaks, but Apple provides a some examples [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) how you should do it. Also a little googling will find a ton of examples on how to do it.

Comment: Now I have solve this issue, I use `scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES`  maybe you now can understand me